# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm not stopping EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created an alarm in Cloudwatch to stop my EC2 instance, if the CPU < 5% for more than five minutes.

[image]

And after five minutes I get the email but the instance continues running.  The instance is using an EBS volume and nothing in the history indicates a problem.

Can someone please tell me why the alarm I setup is not stopping the instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html), you need to create an IAM role so that AWS can automatically stop the instance on your behalf when the alarm is triggered. Also note that you cannot assign an IAM role to an existing instance.

**Update:**

You can now attach to or modify an IAM role of your existing instance. Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/).

Comment: I just created a new instance and a new alarm on that instance and this time the instance shut down as expected. I didn't create a role or assign permissions and it still worked. I'm thinking that there was something about the original instance I created that was preventing the shutdown. I may never know.

Comment: What was the shut down behavior of your instance?

Comment: Hi Mahdi, Since the instance I was using to create this issue is gone and replaced with another, I don't know what really happened. For now, the alarms in Cloudwatch are shutting down the instance as expected

Comment: @Mahdi as time marches on things change, you can indeed now add/change the IAM Role under which an instance runs (since early 2017 I think)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to aws part,hope this may help...not sure...
**Amazon EBS** may not send metric data for an available volume that is not attached to an Amazon EC2 instance, because there is no metric activity to be monitored for that volume. If you have an alarm set for such a metric, you may notice its state change to Insufficient Data. This may simply be an indication that your resource is inactive, and may not necessarily mean that there is a problem.

Comment: HI, The alarm I setup is configured for CPU utilization and not activity on an EBS volume. Where do you see EBS in the alarm setup?